# file contents of different versions in Sharepoint Online not getting downloaded using REST Call

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I am trying to download a file with its major and minor versions of the file using REST API in java. I am able to download only the latest version of the particular file and when I try to download the other versions of the file I am getting 500 Internal Server Error.

The URL to get the versions of the file returns all the versions of the file correctly. When I try to get the content of the different versions I get 500 Internal Server Error.

The URL I used to get the different versions of the file is

> "**_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('%s')/Versions**".

The URL I used to get the content of the file is

> "**_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('%s')/$value**".

The URL syntax for latest version of the file is

> "https://*tenant_name*.sharepoint.com/*folder_name/file_name*".

The URL syntax for versions of the file is

> "https://*tenant_name*.sharepoint.com/_vti_history/*version_id*/*folder_name/file_name*".

Is there any problem with the latter syntax(i.e)URL syntax for file versions?

Anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is **not** supported to specify url for a file version in endpoint `/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl` since it excepts server relative url of actual file.

Since there is nothing wrong with the provided url for a file version you could consider a different approach to download it. Instead of utilizing REST endpoint for a file content `/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('%s')/$value`, consider to download a file using *absolute* url as demonstrated in the example below:

C# example

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var targetPath = @"c:\downloads";
    var sourceFileUrl = String.Format("{0}/_vti_history/512/Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx",webUri);
    var response = client.GetAsync(sourceFileUrl).Result;

    var targetFileName = targetPath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFileUrl);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(targetFileName, response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be:

```
https://sharepoint-site.com/sites/Subsite/_vti_history/version_id/Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx
```